# Vagrant docker provisioner command

Tags: mysql, vagrant, docker

I have a Vagrantfile that installs mysql via docker, and then I would like to run an additional command to create my database. Right now my Vagrantfile has

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
  d.pull_images "tutum/mysql"
  d.run "tutum/mysql",
    args: ' -e MYSQL_PASS="password" --name mysql -p 3306:3306',
end
```

I know I could create a shell provisioner to run the bootstrap script, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it through docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cmd option to specify the cmd argument of the container (More info : https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd)

Example :

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
  d.run "ubuntu",
    cmd: "bash -l",
    args: "-v '/vagrant:/var/www'"
end
```

Comment: The image I'm using already has a CMD argument so I think this would override it.

Comment: Yep it would override it. If you want to launch multiple process inside a docker container it would be wise to use a supervisor. http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/